# Add new IP address to my hosting

Tags: networking, server, ip

I'm sory if its already answered but I'm very newbie and as I can see the other answers interfaces configurations are different than mine and I'm confused and worried about doing something wrong.

My hosting main ip address is:

```
IP: 85.25.x.y
```

I'm requested a new IP from my hosting which is:

```
IP : 62.75.a.b
Netmask : 255.255.255.255
```

I ping this new IP address but cant get response i googled and i think i should change my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
Here it is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 85.25.x.y
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 85.25.x.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

How should I change this file?
I really need help, thank you in advanced

---

I did it! it was so simple! !

I just add below lines and type /etc/init.d/networking restart

```
auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet static
  address 62.11.22.33
  netmask 255.255.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the terminal editor nano to do that.
Since it is a root directory, type

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

now you can edit this file with nano. To exit simply type ctrl+x and y to save your changes.